# AgentWork Trigger After Update is not cover using test class

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, after-trigger, omnichannel

I am writing a trigger On AgentWork with helper class. I have to write a trigger helper test class to cover helper class. Helper class successfully cover but trigger not cover for the helper test class. So, I have created a new test class for AgentWorkTrigger test class. I can share my trigger code.

```
trigger AgentWorkTrigger on AgentWork (After Update) {
    // only after update works
    if (trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter) {
        CaseTriggerHelper.updateCaseStatusonOmniAgentWork(trigger.new);
    }
}




@isTest
static void test_method_omni_status_update() {
    // create test Context
    testContext testData = new testContext();

    System.assert(testData.accList.size() > 0, 'There should be some test Accounts created');

    System.assert(testData.cntList.size() > 0, 'There should be some test Contacts created');

    // Create a new case
    List<Case> csList = Util_TestData.createCases(1, true, new Map<String, String> {'AccountId' => testData.accList[0].id, 'ContactId' => testData.cntList[0].id, 'Reason' => 'Account Access', 'Sub_Topic__c' => 'Sign-on'});

    AgentWork agentWork = null;
    // now do batch uidpates
    Test.startTest();
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.id = UserInfo.getUserId();
    system.debug('user1'+user1);
    System.runAs(user1) {
        agentWork = createAgentWorks(csList, user1).get(0);
        system.debug('agentWork'+agentWork);
        insert agentWork;
        update agentWork;
    }

    Test.stopTest();


}
public static List<AgentWork> createAgentWorks(List<Case> cases, User user) {
    ServiceChannel sc = [SELECT Id
                         FROM ServiceChannel
                         WHERE DeveloperName = 'Inbound_Cases'
                                 LIMIT 1];
    PresenceUserConfig puc = [SELECT Id
                              FROM PresenceUserConfig
                              WHERE DeveloperName = 'Email'
                                      LIMIT 1];
    ServicePresenceStatus sps = [SELECT Id
                                 FROM ServicePresenceStatus
                                 WHERE DeveloperName = 'Available_Cases'
                                         LIMIT 1];
    List<AgentWork> agentWorks = new List<AgentWork>();

    for (Case testCase : cases) {
        agentWorks.add(new AgentWork(ServiceChannelId = sc.Id,
                                     WorkItemId = testCase.Id,
                                     UserId = user.Id));
    }

    return agentWorks;
}

/**
 * test data setup
 */
@TestSetup
static void testDataSetUp() {

    // Create Users
    Profile profile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = : Util_TestData.PROFILE_SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR];
    List<User> lstUser = Util_TestData.createUsers(2, true, new Map<String, String> {'ProfileId' => profile.id});


    list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();
    // create Accounts
    accList = Util_TestData.createAccounts(1, true, new Map<String, String> {'OwnerId' => lstUser[0].id});

    List<Contact> cntList = Util_TestData.createContacts(1, true, new Map<String, String> {'AccountId' => accList[0].id, 'Email' => TEST_EMAIL});

}
/**
 * create Test Context
 */
public class testContext {
    public List<Contact> cntList;
    public List<Account> accList;
    public List<User> userList;



    public testContext() {
        // get Users
        userList = new List<User>([Select id, Name from User where lastname like 'LastName%' and isActive = true and UserType = 'Standard']);

        // get Accounts
        accList = new List<Account>([Select id, Name from Account]);

        // get Contacts
        cntList = new List<Contact>([Select id, Name, Email from Contact]);

    }
}
```

> Blockquote
>   How to do? Please help me.

Comment: I answered my way to handle it, you can use it
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107315/how-to-succesfully-test-agentwork-trigger/275208#275208

Comment: Hey  @PranayJaiswal, This is not working. My trigger is not cover.

Comment: Why did you wrote before insert? I manage to cover in my omni channel implementation

Comment: No, I am writing an After Update trigger.

Comment: You have to write blank before insert trigger, it will run and give you some coverage on it.

Comment: yes it's working.But this is not right solution.

Comment: Like the said, other solution is to make test running user active in omni-channel, WHich is not possible everytime or in CI. Some question dont have solution, they just have workarounds

Comment: Ok thank you so much @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score -1):

Yeh, I solve this issue.
You can insert a user whose status is active for a case. This configuration is available in lightning. You can open user and set Omni-channel status.